# Problem with photodiode luminance measurement

Tags: arduino

I am using a BPV22NF photodiode, the problem is that I don't know how to relate the current reading of the photodiode with the intensity of light detected. Looking in the datasheet, I don't find a function of these two quantities either ([Link](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81509/bpv22nf.pdf)). I'm a beginner at this and I may be overlooking something.

Comment: Define "intensity of light" for us. What are you trying to measure? What will these values be used for? Why did you choose PIN-type photodiode, in particular? Why did you use the word *luminance* in your title when this particular diode really isn't meant for such purposes?

Comment: What is your goal? Are you making an IR transmitter-receiver pair? Or are you making a device to measure light level. If the latter, you want something like a BPW21R that is calibrated (and expensive).

Answer (score 3):

> *the problem is that I don't know how to relate the current reading of
> the photodiode with the intensity of light detected. Looking in the
> datasheet, I don't find a function of these two quantities either*

It's the graph of reverse diode current vs light intensity that you should look at: -

[image]

So, you get 80 μA/mW/cm². If you know the active area of your photodiode then you can get a value in μA/watt (the more conventional figure for photodiodes). Oh, that's quoted on page 1 as 7.5 mm² or 0.5625² cm.

That equals 0.5625 x 80 μA/mW = 45 μA/mW = 45 mA/watt.

Comment: note the note: lambda=950nm - if you're not using 950nm illumination there should be another graph to give the relative sensitivity at different wavelengths